# Multiple sub projects with one domain

Tags: nginx

This config part does work with a single php project handled by httpdocs/index.php:

```
location / {
    root /srv/www/trunk/httpdocs;
    index index.php;

    # if file exists return it right away
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # rwrite params
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php$1 last;
        break;
    }

}

# if the request starts with our frontcontroller, pass it on to fastcgi
location ~ ^/index.php {
    root /srv/www/trunk/httpdocs;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/trunk/httpdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

So what I want to have are multiple sub projects.

mydomain.org/branch_r19999 => mapped to /my/root/**branch_r19999**/httpdocs/index.php
mydomain.org/branch_r2909 => mapped to /my/root/**branch_r2909**/httpdocs/index.php

For sure with param rewrite:
mydomain.org/branch_r19999/myparam1/myparam2 => mapped to /my/root/**branch_r19999**/httpdocs/index.php

I tried it with that:

```
   root /srv/www/branches;
   location / {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$/(.+)$ /index.php$2 last;
            break;
        }    

        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
    }

    location ~* "/(branch_r[0-9]+)" {
        alias /srv/www/branches/$1/httpdocs;

        #Serve static files directly.... but how? This doesn't work
        if ($request_filename ~* \.(gif|html|jpe?g|png|ico|js|css|flv|swf|pdf|xml)$ ) {
            break;
        }

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/branches/$1/httpdocs/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; 
   }
```

And I don't want configure the sub projects statically in the config, that would be no problem.

Has anyone a config like this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the regex becomes greedy and captures the whole URL, try limiting it to more precise

```
server {
    index index.php;
    root /srv/www/trunk/httpdocs;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
    }
    location ~* "/(branch_r[0-9]+)" {
        alias /my/root/$1/httpdocs/;
    }
    location /index.php {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I get the same error which I had with some tests before: open() "/srv/www/branches/branch_r2000/httpdocs/branch_r2000" failed (2: No such file or directory), $1 = branch_r2000 is correct, but why is branch_r2000 at the end again?

Comment: o ok I know, we need to change `root` to `alias`, that was a silly mistake from me

Comment: hm better, no error anymore, but now I'm getting endless redirected: /branch_r2000 => /branch_r2000/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php

Comment: hm, try changing `location /index.php` to `location ~* \.php$`

Comment: That isn't the problem, the problem is the alias line. I can comment out the first and third location and still have the redirect problem.

Comment: well why is it just appending `index.php` without prepending `/my/root` or adding `httpdocs`... also just a small tweak replace `~*` with `~^`

Comment: grmpf this problem takes hours of my live. The problem was the slash in the alias directive. I got it working now with index.php, but now everything passes to index.php, this doesn't work for static files like css. I edited the question, fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/branches/$1/httpdocs/index.php; is now static too instead $fastcgi_script_name.